# Can you change the shape of the points in ggeffects or Sjplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, sjplot

I can't figure out how to change the shape of the points in sjplot or ggeffects -
I have

in sJplot:

```
p<-plot_model(my.lm, type = "pred", terms = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"))
```

This makes the points of Var 2 different colors, but I need them to be different shapes.

I can use ggeffects for this, but I still can't figure out how to make an equivalent graph to plot_model in sJplot with different point shapes.

```
g<-ggpredict(my.lm, terms=c("Var1","Var2", "Var3"))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this (like an argument within `plot_model()`).  So, it seems the only option here is the "nuclear option" - which is changing the values in the `$data` layer of the plot object.  It gets a bit "hacky", but it does work.

I'll demonstrate based on [an adaptation of an example in this vignette here](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/blackwhitefigures.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)

data(efc)
y <- ifelse(efc$neg_c_7 < median(na.omit(efc$neg_c_7)), 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(
  y = to_factor(y),
  sex = to_factor(efc$c161sex),
  dep = to_factor(efc$e42dep),
  barthel = efc$barthtot,
  education = to_factor(efc$c172code)
)

set_label(df$y) <- "High Negative Impact"
fit <- glm(y ~., data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

p <- plot_model(fit, colors = "black")
p
```

[image]

Our goal is to change the shape of those points to something else.  First step is to use `ggplot_build()` to pull the information from the object we just created, `p`.

```
qq <- ggplot_build(p)
```

The object, `qq`, is a list containing 3 layers: data, layout, and plot.  Herein, we want to change the information contained in `qq$data`, which has the aesthetics after they have been mapped.  `qq$data` is a list itself, containing 3 tables.  Each of these tables corresponds to a particular geom in the underlying `ggplot2` call.  The first table `qq$data[[1]]`, is for the vline geom.  The third table `qq$data[[3]]` is for all the line segments behind the points (you'll note they have xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax columns).  The second table is the one we want, which is for the point geoms:

```
> qq$data[[2]]
  colour  fill x           y PANEL group shape size alpha stroke
1  black black 7  0.28191638     1     7    19  2.5    NA    0.5
2  black black 6  0.21074532     1     6    19  2.5    NA    0.5
3  black black 5  0.48863767     1     5    19  2.5    NA    0.5
4  black black 4  0.39529220     1     4    19  2.5    NA    0.5
5  black black 3 -0.01294270     1     1    19  2.5    NA    0.5
6  black black 2  0.09837842     1     3    19  2.5    NA    0.5
7  black black 1  0.12316583     1     2    19  2.5    NA    0.5
```

You can see all points are made with `shape=19`.  We can change that, then rebuild the plot from our modified `qq` object like so:

```
qq$data[[2]]$shape <- 5
plot(ggplot_gtable(qq))
```

[image]

We can do fun things like change all sorts of stuff manually in the plot if you want:

```
qq$data[[1]]$colour <- "blue"     # change color of vertical line
qq$data[[2]]$shape[3:5] <- 19     # points 3-5 are now circles again
qq$data[[2]]$color[4:7] <- "red"  # last 4 point are red
qq$data[[2]]$size[c(2,4,6)] <- 4  # some points are bigger

plot(ggplot_gtable(qq))
```

[image]

*A word on saving these files plots to file, if you like to use `ggsave(...)`*:  You cannot save the output of `plot(ggplot_gtable(qq))` directly using `ggsave()`, since  the default value for `plot=` in `ggsave()` is `last_plot()`, which does not work here when using `plot(...)`.  Therefore if you want to save with `ggsave()`, you can do the following:

```
p <- ggplot_gtable(qq)       # save to a large gtable
ggsave("name.png", plot = p  # reference the gtable object
```

Comment: This is such a helpful answer, thanks a lot for debugging this!

Comment: This is such a helpful method, worked like a charm. Thanks so so much, take all my carma. One question: How could I use the altered qq and move on to a grid.arrange(qq, qq2, ncol = 2)? Becuase grid.arrange wants grobs and I need to do this before ggsave.